# Responsive CSS3 chain animation,pausing and resuming issue

Tags: css, animation, responsive-design, css-transitions, css-animations

Am trying to animate using **css3 animation only**,but also having the **responsiveness maintained** till ipad size.
I came across an issue where i need to move the box after the lights have come ON and i cant seem to do it.

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJX6j/)

Here's what i have done so far..

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    height:100%;
}
#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    float : none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

#waveDisplay{
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    height: 7%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16%;
    width: 3%;
    left: 58%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#waveImage{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 76%;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-animation-name:waveMoving;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes waveMoving{
    from{-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);}
    to{-webkit-transform:translateX(-75%);}
}

#innerWrapper{
    border: 2px solid;
    float:none;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;   
    background: no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#background{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.lights{
    max-height:  38.3%;
    max-width: 30%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;

    opacity: 0;
    animation:lightFading 0.1s;
    -moz-animation:lightFading 0.1s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: lightFadingIn 0.1s; /* safari and chrome*/
    -o-animation:lightFading 0.1s; /* Opera */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5.2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes lightFadingIn {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes lightFadingIn { /* Firefox */
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes lightFadingIn { /* Safari and Chrome */
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes lightFadingOut {
    0% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes lightFadingOut { /* Firefox */
    0% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes lightFadingOut { /* Safari and Chrome */
    0% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}

#light1{
    top: 31%;
    left: 14.8%;
}

#light2{
    top: 31%;
    left: 20.2%;
}

#cameraFlash{
    top: 32%;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 21%;

    -webkit-animation-name:  cameraFlashDisplay 2s;
    /*-webkit-animation: cameraFlash 0.2s;*/
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5.2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframe cameraFlashDisplay {
    0% {
        transform: scaleY(0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.0);
        max-height:0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleY(1.0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
        max-height:100%;
    }
}

#box1{
    max-height: 17%;
    max-width: 17%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    left: 5%;

    -webkit-animation-name:boxMoving;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;*/
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes boxMoving{
    from{-webkit-transform:translateX(0%);}
    to{-webkit-transform:translateX(275%);}
}
```

> ```
>  Here's what i need to do in steps after the box has reached the 3lights:
>      1. Lights should turn OFF.
>      2. Box should keep on moving.
> ```

Can anyone help me out with this?
Am kinda new to css3 animation.

*If the fiddle doesn't work,try clearing the cache and running it again.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with it this way [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EJX6j/2/)

```
#box1{
   max-height: 17%;
   max-width: 17%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 52%;
   left: -50px;

   -webkit-animation-name:boxMoving;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
   /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;*/
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes boxMoving{
   0%   { margin-left:-20px;}
   40%   { margin-left:185px;}
   50% { margin-left:185px; }
   100% { margin-left:365px; }
}
```

And change the light and cameraflash animation durations and delays this way

```
.lights{
   max-height:  38.3%;
   max-width: 30%;
   z-index: 100;
   position: absolute;

   opacity: 0;
   animation:lightFading 1s;
   -moz-animation:lightFading 1s; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-animation: lightFadingIn 1s; /* safari and chrome*/
   -o-animation:lightFading 1s; /* Opera */
   -webkit-animation-delay: 2.0s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes lightFadingIn {
   0% {opacity:0;}
   80% {opacity:1;}
   100% {opacity:0;}

}


#cameraFlash{
   top: 32%;
   z-index: 100;
   left: 21%;
   opacity:0;
   -webkit-animation-name:  cameraFlashDisplay 2s;
   /*-webkit-animation: cameraFlash 0.2s;*/
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 2.0s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframe cameraFlashDisplay {
   0% {
      opacity:0;
   }

   80% {
      opacity:1;
   }

   100% {
      opacity:1;
   }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Erm.. the lights doesn't go out after the box has passed,does it?

Comment: Plus is this the only way using css3 animation? 
I mean... using the percentage for the whole animation? 
Cuz i have many more animations to be added along with this...

Comment: edited the code .. check the DEMO for lights off animation after the box passes

Comment: you can use pixels also but for responsive purpose using percentages would be more appropriate

Comment: Oh hey thanx..
and i meant percentage for the keyframes...
Not the measurements of the sizes..

Comment: You're Welcome :) and yes keyframes can be defined in either 'percentages' or 'from' and 'to'